I am searching the title of a movie which I believe was something like "Treasure Planet" but not the one from 2002
In my teenage years (somewhere between 1990 and 2000) I've watched a TV series (I believe it was at least 2-4 episodes) which in my language was translated like "The Treasure Planet". It was based on Robert Louis Stevenson's "Treasure Island" except that it was in space. As long as I remember it was very close to the book - the characters were the same and the storyline was similar with the the one in the book (except the space, of course). The movie was not animation.
Now, when I search online, the only movie I found with such title is "the Treasure Planet" from 2002. I searched via Google and IMDB but couldn't find any information about it.
Does somebody know about such TV movie?
Maybe I am mistaken that it was a TV movie, but I've watched it on TV. for sure I would predate it before 2000 or even (but not sure) before 1995. Not sure about the nationality of the movie.


"Treasure Island in Outer Space" (original: Il Pianeta Del Tesoro - Treasure Planet) is a 1987 science fiction Italian and German television miniseries directed by Antonio Margheriti.
  It is based on the novel Treasure Island by Robert Louis Stevenson, setting the story in space in the year 2300.





It seems that this is the right answer. Will check it and will mark it as accepted answer.
